# Wavefront to send Different Alert of the metric if it's from Different Source

Tags: wavefront

I am sending data to a single metric  from 2 different machine/sources (SourceA and SourceB).

When my alert condition is TRUE for both sources :  I get a single email mentioning ALERT CONDITION is true and sources are mentioned below.

---

Can I send 2 different alert/emails in this case ?

One for SourceA and another for SourceB

Answer (score 0):

Wavefront aggregates failing time-series for a single alert by default. If you want separate notifications, you'll have to split them into multiple alerts.